# CKEditor Backslashes

Tags: php, sql, ckeditor

I'm using this query in PHP:

```
$s = " UPDATE articles SET Article_Name='$title', Category_Name='$cat', Content='$content'  WHERE ID=$ID";  
$insert = mysqli_query($dbc, $s);
If ($insert){
    echo "<div id='success'>Updated successfully!</div>";
} else {
    echo "<div id='failed'>Update failed!</div>";
}
```

$content is posted from a form on the same page:

```
<div id="postContent"><textarea name="theContent" ><?php echo $Content ?></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">                      
            CKEDITOR.replace('theContent')
    </script>
</div>
```

So "theContent" is what gets posted and then set as $content.

The problem is that if I add a backslash (\) anywhere to the text content written n CKEditor, it's gets ripped out. I tried adding \\ to escape the backslash and it worked the first time, but of course the second time there was only one \ remaining so it again got ripped out...escaped!

I thought I'd try and be a smart arse and add some string replace that replaces \ with \\ but PHP didn't like that. 
Does anyone know how I can solve this issue please?

I've also just noticed as I am typing this, that this site does the same thing as I have needed to double up on the backslashes, but I'm betting they won't disappear after editing!

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: N.B. Fixing the above is also quite likely to help with your stated problem, since it will escape the inputs properly.

Comment: If you still have an issue after that, you can check the content of the database, vs the content of what you see on screen, and see if it's actually a presentation-layer problem.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, yes you are absolutely correct. I had been using MeekroDB in my last project which did all that for me so I'm a bit rusty with the vanilla sql. I'll alter it later today and see if that makes any difference to the issue I'm having. It's only a production site at the minute anyway, not live, but glad you picked me up on it!

Comment: No problem. P.S. in common terminology "production" means the same as "live". Did you mean "development" or "test" or "UAT" perhaps?

Comment: Ha, I obviously meant development not production..although I am producing, I have not yet produced!

Comment: No probs! have you made any progress trying to fix the issue? If you're still stuck, provide us with your latest code and any error messages / unexpected results etc.

Comment: Yep, that did actually solve the issue of the backslashes. Thanks for the help ADyson.